# Sonarqube 6.0: How can an issue be assiged to an user from a plugin?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

What type of SQ plugin interface should I use for assignment of issues to an user? Sensor, MeasureComputer, other?

What would be the main related classes and/or interfaces? Any source file to check?

Answer (score 2):

Issues are automatically assigned by SonarQube. This behaviour cannot be overridden/changed by a plugin.